# Neo4j ExecutionEngine does not return valid results

Tags: java, neo4j

Trying to use a similar example from the sample code found [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.1.0-M01/community/cypher/cypher-docs/src/test/java/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/JavaQuery.java)

My sample function is:

```
void query()

{
    String nodeResult = "";
    String rows = "";
    String resultString;
    String columnsString;

    System.out.println("In query");
    // START SNIPPET: execute
    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );

    ExecutionResult result;
    try ( Transaction ignored = graphDb.beginTx() )
    {
        result = engine.execute( "start n=node(*) where n.Name =~ '.*79.*' return n, n.Name" );
        // END SNIPPET: execute
        // START SNIPPET: items
        Iterator<Node> n_column = result.columnAs( "n" );
        for ( Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable( n_column ) )
        {
            // note: we're grabbing the name property from the node,
            // not from the n.name in this case.
            nodeResult = node + ": " + node.getProperty( "Name" );
            System.out.println("In for loop");
            System.out.println(nodeResult);

        }
        // END SNIPPET: items



        // START SNIPPET: columns
        List<String> columns = result.columns();
        // END SNIPPET: columns

        // the result is now empty, get a new one
        result = engine.execute( "start n=node(*) where n.Name =~ '.*79.*' return n, n.Name" );
        // START SNIPPET: rows
        for ( Map<String, Object> row : result )
        {
            for ( Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet() )
            {
                rows += column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ";
                System.out.println("nested");
            }
            rows += "\n";
        }
        // END SNIPPET: rows
        resultString = engine.execute( "start n=node(*) where n.Name =~ '.*79.*' return n.Name"  ).dumpToString();
        columnsString = columns.toString();
        System.out.println(rows);
        System.out.println(resultString);
        System.out.println(columnsString);

        System.out.println("leaving");

    }

}
```

When I run this in the web console I get many results (as there are multiple nodes that have an attribute of Name that contains the pattern 79.  Yet running this code returns no results.  The debug print statements 'in loop' and 'nested' never print either.  Thus this must mean there are not results found in the Iterator, yet that doesn't make sense.

And yes, I already checked and made sure that the `graphDb` variable is the same as the path for the web console.  I have other code earlier that uses the same variable to write to the database.

EDIT - More info
If I place the contents of query in the same function that creates my data, I get the correct results.  If I run the query by itself it returns nothing.  It's almost as the query works only in the instance where I add the data and not if I come back to the database cold in a separate instance.

EDIT2 -

Here is a snippet of code that shows the bigger context of how it is being called and sharing the same DBHandle

```
package ContextEngine;

import ContextEngine.NeoHandle;
import java.util.LinkedList;


/*
 * Class to handle streaming data from any coded source
 */
public class Streamer {

    private NeoHandle myHandle;

    private String contextType;

    Streamer()
    {

    }


    public void openStream(String contextType)
    {

        myHandle = new NeoHandle();
        myHandle.createDb();
    }

    public void streamInput(String dataLine)
    {
        Context context = new Context();
        /*
         * get database instance
         * write to database
         * check for errors
         * report errors & success
         */
        System.out.println(dataLine);

        //apply rules to data (make ContextRules do this, send type and string of data)
        ContextRules contextRules = new ContextRules();
        context = contextRules.processContextRules("Calls", dataLine);

        //write data (using linked list from contextRules)
        NeoProcessor processor = new NeoProcessor(myHandle);
        processor.processContextData(context);
    }

    public void runQuery()
    {
        NeoProcessor processor = new NeoProcessor(myHandle);
        processor.query();

    }

    public void closeStream()
    {
        /*
         * close database instance
         */
        myHandle.shutDown();
    }

}
```

Now, if I call streamInput AND query in in the same instance (parent calls) the query returns results.  If I only call query and do not enter ANY data in that instance (yet web console shows data for same query) I get nothing.  Why would I have to create the Nodes and enter them into the database at runtime just to return a valid query.  Shouldn't I ALWAYS get the same results with such a query?

Comment: Perhaps you can share an example project on github that exposes this incorrect behavior, eg. in a unit test?

Comment: I'll do that.  Let me first try the option below, then clean some non-neo4j stuff (special sauce for my app) up, validate the issue exists and then post.  Should help us all, and I owe you guys a full example with the help you have provided.

Comment: Michael - I created a git repo with my test.  You can find it here:  https://github.com/gramsky/Neo4jTest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention that you are using the Neo4j Browser, which comes with Neo4j. However, the example you posted is for Neo4j Embedded, which is the in-process version of Neo4j. Are you sure you are talking to the same database when you try your query in the Browser?

In order to talk to Neo4j Server from Java, I'd recommend looking at the Neo4j JDBC driver, which has good support for connecting to the Neo4j server from Java.

http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc

You can set up a simple connection by adding the Neo4j JDBC jar to your classpath, available here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/releases Then just use Neo4j as any JDBC driver:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");
ResultSet rs = conn.executeQuery("start n=node({id}) return id(n) as id", map("id", id));

while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getLong("id"));
}
```

Refer to the JDBC documentation for more advanced usage.

To answer your question on why the data is not durably stored, it may be one of many reasons. I would attempt to incrementally scale back the complexity of the code to try and locate the culprit. For instance, until you've found your problem, do these one at a time:

1. Instead of looping through the result, print it using System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
2. Instead of the regex query, try just MATCH (n) RETURN n, to return all data in the database
3. Make sure the data you are seeing in the browser is not "old" data inserted earlier on, but really is an insert from your latest run of the Java program. You can verify this by deleting the data via the browser before running the Java program using MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->() DELETE n,r;
4. Make sure you are actually working against the same database directories. You can verify this by leaving the server running. If you can still start your java program, unless your Java program is using the Neo4j REST Bindings, you are not using the same directory. Two Neo4j databases cannot run against the same database directory simultaneously.

Comment: Data is being committed.  If I go to the console I see the data. I also added more code showing how I am using the same database each time.

Comment: Keep in mind query() is a seperate function within the NeoProcessor class but using the same NeoHandle reference.  This call is made after the transaction to commit data to the database.  If I comment out the streamInput call in the referring method, the query returns nothing.  If I call that method, the query returns data.  Each call to processContextData has its own transaction.  I can post that too if you need to see that.

Comment: Someone else recommended the jdbc driver.  Yet if that is the preferred method, why do the embedded options show up as the primary methods on the Neo4j site?  Additionally I cannot find a single example of how to use JDC for Neo4j.  Are you aware of any simple way to use it to interact with Neo4j, much less do the same query I am trying to run?

Comment: Also, I'm just using the browser to see the data that is in the database after my java program runs.  I've yet to see any documentation that explains why I cannot do that.

Comment: If you run the embedded database in the same directory as in the server, then you're right, it will work. JDBC is not yet the recommended way to talk to Neo4j through Java. This is mainly because Neo4j used to be mainly an embedded Java database, and that the move to DBMS is not fully complete in Java, specifically, there are still discussions to be had about preferred access methods. Still, in my personal opinion, JDBC is by far the best option today. I'll add an example for starting the JDBC driver to my response.

Comment: Updated the answer with the JDBC example, and a checklist of things you could try to help diagnose your issue.

Comment: Thanks, though the code you gave has some errors and I'm confused what you are trying to do.  What is the 'map' doing?  Additionally, as you have it coded the last id is giving a syntax error and will not compile.

Comment: Also, where can I find documentation on HOW to use JDBC with neo4j?  The link you gave has a link to a blog post with very few examples.  The few documentation like links from that page all reference a REST API and not how JDBC integrates with that.  Is there a link that used to exist on that page that no longer exist?  Sorry, I'm just not seeing ANYTHING that shows how you use JDBC as a way to interface with Neo4j.

Comment: Also, regarding the 4 steps to consider, what do you mean 'two neo4j databases'?  I'm not runnign two databases.  I only have one neo4j process running.  I am using the same data path for the web console as the Java embedded program.  I don't consider that two databases but rather two ways to access the same database.  In MySQL you can access a single database via the command line, any web portal as well as programming language connections (Python, Java, PHP, etc.) all at the same time.  Does neo4j NOT support a similar interface methodology?

Comment: I ended up changing ResultSet rs = conn.executeQuery("start n=node({id}) return id(n) as id", map("id", id));
 to   ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("start n=node(*) where n.Name =~ '.*79.*' return n, n.Name");
and that removed syntax errors but I'm now getting an apache runtime error of Unexpected token END_ARRAY.

Comment: @WildBill ugh, that sounds like a bug in the JDBC driver. I'm sorry you're having so much pain with this. Could you please open an issue containing the code you run to get that error here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/issues

Comment: @WildBill re: "two databases", sorry I should've used the word "two instances", you can't run two Neo4j instances against the same database folder at the same time. Neo4j supports this in the same way MySQL does - you start a database server (mysqld or Neo4j Server), and then any process can connect to that server to talk to the database. It often gets very confused because of Neo4j Embedded, which is an in-process Neo4j instance that cannot be running against the same directory as another Neo4j instance is running simultaneously.

Comment: I created a git repo with my embedded code (as well as commented out JDBC code).  It can be found here:  https://github.com/gramsky/Neo4jTest.  I'll visit the location above as well.

Comment: And in true fashion after creating repo I have it working :/  Your latest comment about "two databases" led me to do more testing.  I started shutting down the database when I ran my java code.  I also realized the 'clearDb' found in the HelloWorld Neo4j example should not be run to persist data.  I though that was required to release the lock on the database but it was the concurrency issue I was creating.  I'll still submit the JDBC bug as well though I have the embedded stuff working.

Comment: I've submitted a bounty for the sole purpose of awarding it to you for your detailed help in this manner.  I'm not allowed to award it for another 23 hours, but it is coming.

Comment: @WildBill glad you got it working - and many thanks for the bounty, my meager SO score could use a boost :p Sorry for the rough start, I hope you'll have a grand time using neo, and welcome to the world of graphs!